# How to make C-g cancel evil-replace rather than typing ^G?

Tags: evil

In evil mode, the <kbd>r</kbd> command, `evil-replace`, waits for a replacement character to be typed and replaces the current character with it. Sometimes I hit <kbd>r</kbd> by mistake and wish to cancel, so I hit <kbd>C-g</kbd>. Instead of cancelling the `evil-replace`, however, it replaces the current character with the escape code `^G` which I then have to undo.

Is there a way to make <kbd>C-g</kbd> cancel the `evil-replace`, like <kbd>esc</kbd> does?

**Update: this is now built in to `evil`.** See https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/pull/1111. The answers below now only apply to legacy `evil` versions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this using advice (I know that's not ideal, and I'm new to advice, so the code that follows probably isn't great)

```el
(defun replace-control-g-with-nil (char)
  "Make C-g read as nil so that `r C-g` cancels the replace."
  (let ((control-g-char ?\a))
    (if (eq char control-g-char)
        (progn
          (message "Quit")  ; Without calling message, the cursor stays looking like replace
          nil)              ; Returning nil cancels the evil-replace
      char)))

(advice-add 'evil-read-key :filter-return 'replace-control-g-with-nil)
```

Comment: You can get the `control-g-char` with `?\C-g` as well, might be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  If you inspect `evil-replace-state-map` with `F1 v`, you'll notice it has `ESC` bound to `evil-normal-state`.  You can do the same for `C-g` as well:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(define-key evil-replace-state-map (kbd "C-g") 'evil-normal-state))
```

Comment: It looks like evil-replace-state-map is for when you hit `R` to replace multiple characters. Unfortunately key bindings there don't affect the single character `r` behavior